# I want to block all IP address except office IP using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to block ip from particular country but i need to give access only few ip address to the country using htaccess or any other way?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to do that in PHP?

Comment: This might help - https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx.

Comment: Remember that you can never block a whole "country", people use proxies and VPS's to bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .htaccess file

```
<ifModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable On

#Add countries you wish to deny here

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CO DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE EG DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE HI DenyCountry

Allow from all
Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx

Deny from env=DenyCountry
</ifModule>
```

And a list of 2 digit country codes can be found here:
https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/